# Как создать дерево выражений с запросом Any + StartsWith

Tags: c#, linq2sql, expressions

Имеется вот такой код который получает нужные мне данные из бд, нужно переделать вместо Contains сделать `Any(c => c.StartsWith(value));`

```
protected static Expression GetInListExpression(Expression property, Expression value)
{
    var querableVal = Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "AsQueryable", null, value),
        typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(property.Type));

    return Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Contains", new[] { property.Type }, querableVal, property);
}
```

Comment: Что мешает заменить Contains на Any?

Comment: зачем вообще собирать `.AsQueryable().[Method]` с помощью выражений?

Comment: @Grundy это было сделанно очень давно и не мной, моя задача заменить Contains на Any + StartsWith, Я знаю что ничего не мешает заменить Contains на Any, но как добавить StartsWith???

Comment: С деревом Expression я вообще не знаком, для меня это устаревшие технологии

Comment: А что же тогда не устаревшие технологии? :)

Comment: _как добавить StartsWith?_ - точно так же собираешь Expression, и передаешь параметром после `property`